# Preventing a Popup from Reappearing in the Same Session Using Google Tag Manager (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, I've created a script containing a popup that is displayed under certain conditions. Specifically, I have two associated triggers that launch the script:

- after a 30-second delay (I use a custom code that pushes the event `timer_elapsed` in the data layer after 30 seconds)
- after scrolling 50% of the page (I use the Scroll Depth trigger from GTM)

These two triggers are configured separately from this script. So the script can be triggered by the delay or the scrolling .

While testing in GTM's Preview mode, when I open a page, the popup does indeed show after 30 seconds. Then I close it, and it disappears. However, the problem arises when I scroll down to 50%; the popup reappears and no longer closes (and it reappears without the good translation defined by my `{{DL - locale}}` data layer variable.

To avoid bothering the user, I don't want the popup to show twice in the same session. So if it's displayed once (regardless of the trigger), it shouldn't reappear at all for the duration of that session.

How can I modify my script to ensure that the popup, once closed, does not reappear in the same user session regardless of meeting the trigger conditions again?

```
// Function to check if the popup session is active
function isPopupSessionActive() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('popupSession') === 'active';
}

// Function to set the popup session as active
function setPopupSessionActive() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('popupSession', 'active');
}

// Function to close the popup
function closePopup() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
    console.log("Popup closed");
}

// Function to translate the popup content
function translatePopup(locale) {
    var translations = {
        'en': {
            'title': "End of year offer",
            'text': "Get <strong>500€ off</strong> on online bootcamps starting in 2023",
            'button': "Discover Online Bootcamps"
        },
        'fr': {
            'title': "End of year offer",
            'text': "Get a <strong>500€ discount</strong> on online bootcamps starting in 2023",
            'button': "Discover Online Bootcamps"
        },
        // other translations...
    };

    var localeTranslations = translations[locale] || translations['en'];
    document.querySelector('#popup .split-right h2').innerHTML = localeTranslations.title;
    document.querySelector('#popup .split-right p').innerHTML = localeTranslations.text;
    document.querySelector('#popup .split-right button').textContent = localeTranslations.button;
}

// Function to initialize the popup
function initPopup() {
    if (!isPopupSessionActive()) {
        var userLocale = "{{DL - locale}}"; // Replace with your method of obtaining the locale
        translatePopup(userLocale);

        var popupElement = document.getElementById('popup');
        if (popupElement.style.display === 'block') {
            console.log("The popup is already visible.");
            return;
        }

        popupElement.style.display = 'block';
        setPopupSessionActive();
        console.log("Popup displayed");

        var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-btn");
        if (closeButton.getAttribute("data-listener") !== "true") {
            closeButton.addEventListener("click", closePopup);
            closeButton.setAttribute("data-listener", "true");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("The popup has already been shown or closed. Cancelling new initialization.");
    }
}

// Initialize the popup when the script loads
initPopup();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="popup" class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <span class="close-btn" onclick="closePopup()">&times;</span>
      <div class="split-left">
        <img src="#">
      </div>
      <div class="split-right">
        <h2>End of year offer</h2>
        <p>Get <strong>500€ off</strong> on online bootcamps starting in 2023</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="cta-popup">Discover Online Bootcamps</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.cta-popup{
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: #670BFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.88rem 1.4rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.cta-popup:hover{
    background-color: #5809d9;
}
.split-popup{
    grid: 1fr;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.split-left{
    grid: 2fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.split-left > img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.split-right{
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 99999;
}
.popup-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.5fr;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're already using sessionStorage to say that it's active, but I think if you set a key value pair to check on each of the functions whether or not it's been seen, you would get the result you're looking for.

If you have fired off the modal, set the storage value to true. That way when the other fires off you can evaluate the key value to decide whether or not to show it.

```js
//check to see if it's been seen yet before running code inside your function
let seenModal = sessionStorage.getItem('seen-modal');
if(!seenModal) {
  //your code inside the function that runs ONLY if you have not seen the modal yet
  
  //this goes in at the end to keep set the value that it has been seen
  sessionStorage.setItem('seen-modal', true);
}
```